# How do i find ∠QPR

Tags: trigonometry

> Port Q is 45 nautical miles from port P on a bearing of 055°T. Port R is 65 nautical miles from port P, and ∠PQR = 90°
>
> Find ∠QPR to the nearest degree

The answer is probably pretty straight forward, but i just dont understand how i can figure it out .

Here is a diagram

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bearing has nothing to do with angle $\angle QPR$. It just rotates the triangle $QPR$.

By definition:

$$\cos\angle QPR=\frac{QP}{PR}=\frac{45}{65}=\frac{9}{13}$$

Therefore:

$$\angle QPR = \arccos\frac{9}{13}\approx 46^\circ$$